# Distance from point to point in a network, anylogic

Tags: networking, distance, point, anylogic, agent

I want to calculate the distance between two agents or between the two points of the agents using the network paths.
I tried `getDistance(Point source, Point target, ShortestPathData<N,P> data)` -> `getDistance(Point(vx,vy), Point(a.getX(),a.getY()), d);` with `double d = 0.0;`, `vx = a.getX()`  and  `vy = a.getY()` . vx and vy are the coordinates of the second agent. The agents are from the same type, let's call it type one. I typed the code in the statechart of the agent type two.
=> Problem-description: The method Point (double, double) is undefined for type two.
How do I solve this problem? Or is there another function i could use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is doable using the function you are trying to use, but that function is effectively complex internal (undocumented) AnyLogic code relating to how agents move across networks 'under the covers' (when asked to do so via blocks or `moveTo` function calls). I wouldn't want to guarantee that this will stay the same in future releases (and requires a good understanding of Java).

(Agents in GIS space have a `distanceByRoute` function to get the distance via the GIS space to another agent, but there is no equivalent for agents in networks I am aware of. Typically, though, you don't need to use the distance-by-path, so what exactly is your reason for needing it? Even where you do, it may often be good enough just to use the straight-line distance, which you can get via the `getDistance` functions in agents, not the `getDistance` functions for a network.)

That said, this can work as below...

The `getDistance` function (Java method) you are trying to call only exists on a `Network` object (where the network is the 'parent' of all the nodes and paths in a connected network). Plus you have to create (instantiate) `Point` objects (there is no `Point` function) *and* get the `ShortestPathData` for the network and from/to points in question. (This shortest-path-data represents the calculated route between two points, and you can then get the distance between any set of points on that route.)

So you'd have code something like the below, where `agent1` and `agent2` are references to your two agents in question, and `network` is the nodes/paths network (assuming this code is in the agent that contains this network):

```
Point p1 = new Point(agent1.getX(), agent1.getY());
Point p2 = new Point(agent2.getX(), agent2.getY());

ShortestPathData<Node, Path> pathData = network.getPathData(p1, p2, null);
double distance = network.getDistance(p1, p2, pathData);
```

(Since the distance is returned in pixels, you may want to convert that to an appropriate length unit using the current Scale of the agent containing the network, via something like `scale.toLengthUnits(distance, METER)`.)

Comment: Ive  noticed you can skip ShortestPathData calculation. The following code works just fine for me: Point p1 = new Point(agent1.getX(), agent1.getY());
Point p2 = new Point(agent2.getX(), agent2.getY());
double distance = network.getDistance(p1, p2, null);